# Typescript and Vue.js - property is used before its initialization

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Here is my code

```
export default class PrimitiveLink extends Vue {
  style = {
    // Reset
    display: 'inline-block',
    textDecoration: 'none',
    outline: 'none',
    // Theme
    ...this.themeStyle,
  };

  @Prop(String) readonly href!: string
  @Prop(String) readonly title: string | undefined
  @Prop(Object) readonly themeStyle!: object
}
```

I am getting TypeScript error `Property 'themeStyle' is used before its initialization.`
What does that mean and how should I fix it? Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: I used the default value for a prop, but still getting this error.

@Prop({ default: () => "" })
  body;

httpBody: string = this.body

Error: "Property 'body' is used before its initialization.Vetur(2729)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class properties/fields are syntactic sugar for constructor body code and evaluated in the same order they are defined:

```
constructor() {    
  this.style = {
    /* ... */
    ...this.themeStyle, // not defined
  };

  this.themeStyle /* = ... */;
}
```

This order also applies to TypeScript properties that are not initialized and doesn't exist at runtime. `themeStyle` should go before `style`.

The problem with this snippet is that it doesn't conform to Vue lifecycle. Prop values aren't available at the time class instance is created, `themeStyle` is expected to be undefined.

`style` should be either computed property to react to `themeStyle` changes:

```
get style() {
  return {
    // Reset
    display: 'inline-block',
    textDecoration: 'none',
    outline: 'none',
    // Theme
    ...this.themeStyle,
  };
}
```

Or be assigned at the time `themeStyle` is available:

```
style!: object;

mounted() {
  this.style = {
    display: 'inline-block',
    textDecoration: 'none',
    outline: 'none',
    ...this.themeStyle,
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation. I like the usage of computed methods.

Answer (score 0):

it just means that you have used `themeStyle` before initializing it.

essentially something like this:

```js
var a = themeStyle;
var themeStyle = "something";
```

The solution is to define `themeStyle` before you use it.

Alternatively, you can use `...this['themeStyle']` which TypeScript would allow, but only if you can't solve it "properly".